# CIGaussianBlur issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

After much research I found out how to get iOS's CIGaussianBlur to semi work. I am trying to blur an UIImageView, but instead it's blurring the entire view. Here is my code:

```
// Get a UIImage from the UIView
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Blur the UIImage
CIImage *imageToBlur = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:viewImage.CGImage];
CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[gaussianBlurFilter setValue:imageToBlur forKey:@"inputImage"];
[gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
CIImage *resultImage = [gaussianBlurFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
UIImage *endImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:resultImage];

// Place the UIImage in a UIImageView
_backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
_backgroundImage.image = endImage;
[self.view addSubview:_backgroundImage];
```

(My UIImageView's name is backgroundImage)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create the iOS 7 blur? If so you can use this category...

https://github.com/iGriever/TWSReleaseNotesView/tree/master/TWSReleaseNotesView

It is one that an apple employee released to make it easy to recreate the iOS 7 blur.

Just take the snap shot and then use the category to "applyLightEffects" etc...